# Can anyone tell me a better and free alternative to sumblime text editor?

Tags: text-editor

I am using sublime text editor for last few months...Recently I have decided to create a video tutorial...but the message that sublime shows (it is unregistered) is annoying...So can anyone tell me an alternative that works exactly like sublime (something that can ease your life while working on some project)...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of code you're working with, you can give [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) or [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) a try too